# Ubuntu stuck on spalsh screen, with weird workaround

Tags: boot, screen, 21.10

Sometimes when I boot ubuntu on my Lenovo idepad duet 10igl5 with intel celeron n4020 with Intel uhd, I get stuck on the lenovo spalsh screen, and the only weird workaround that I've found is to enter the bios, change nothing and then exit and save, and then it boots normally, I don't mind it, but it's an inconvenience

[Link to problem, video](https://twitter.com/Xellerate5635/status/1516449261835141132?t=fa6E7mlNc-Bp4kban8YEbg&s=19)

Comment: Hello. Have you checked to see if there is a BIOS update for the machine?

Comment: This "Ideapad" logo is part of you (UEFI) hardware and has nothing to do with any operating system. Wrong place to ask - this is a lenovo problem. (And not a nice one. If there is warranty on the device go immediately to your local dealer or send it in)

Comment: I've got the latest bios update, I had to reinstall windows just to make sure, and also what about the wierd solution that I found

Comment: I don't know if it's something enabled in the bios causing it